# javadoc generator

Tags: java

How to solve this problem
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
C:\Users\Ramaraj>cd\

C:\>set path="D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin";

C:\>javadoc D:\PersonAction.java -d D:\doc
Creating destination directory: "D:\doc\"
Loading source file D:\PersonAction.java...
D:\PersonAction.java:22: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
//σ«ÜΣ╣ëσ??Σ╕║reloadτÜäresultΘç?σ«Üσ?æσê░user.action, σà╢Σ╗ûresultσêÖµîëτàºconve
ntionΘ╗ÿΦ«ñ.
         ^
D:\PersonAction.java:22: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
//σ«ÜΣ╣ëσ??Σ╕║reloadτÜäresultΘç?σ«Üσ?æσê░user.action, σà╢Σ╗ûresultσêÖµîëτàºconve
ntionΘ╗ÿΦ«ñ.
          ^
D:\PersonAction.java:22: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
//σ«ÜΣ╣ëσ??Σ╕║reloadτÜäresultΘç?σ«Üσ?æσê░user.action, σà╢Σ╗ûresultσêÖµîëτàºconve
ntionΘ╗ÿΦ«ñ.
                               ^
D:\PersonAction.java:22: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
//σ«ÜΣ╣ëσ??Σ╕║reloadτÜäresultΘç?σ«Üσ?æσê░user.action, σà╢Σ╗ûresultσêÖµîëτàºconve
ntionΘ╗ÿΦ«ñ.
                                    ^
D:\PersonAction.java:32: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
        private Page<Person> page = new Page<Person>(15);//µ»?Θí╡5µ?íΦ«░σ╜ò
                                                             ^
D:\PersonAction.java:32: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
        private Page<Person> page = new Page<Person>(15);//µ»?Θí╡5µ?íΦ«░σ╜ò
                                                                   ^
D:\PersonAction.java:65: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
                //Φ«╛τ╜«Θ╗ÿΦ«ñµÄÆσ║?µû╣σ╝?
                                   ^
D:\PersonAction.java:65: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
                //Φ«╛τ╜«Θ╗ÿΦ«ñµÄÆσ║?µû╣σ╝?
                                         ^
D:\PersonAction.java:82: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
                addActionMessage("Σ┐?σ¡ÿµê?σèƒ");
                                    ^
D:\PersonAction.java:82: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
                addActionMessage("Σ┐?σ¡ÿµê?σèƒ");
                                          ^
D:\PersonAction.java:90: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
                        addActionMessage("σêáΘÖñµê?σèƒ");
                                                  ^
D:\PersonAction.java:110: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
        //-- Θí╡Θ?óσ▒₧µÇºΦ«┐Θù«σç╜µò░ --//
                 ^
D:\PersonAction.java:112: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
         * listΘí╡Θ?óµÿ╛τñ║τö¿µê╖σêåΘí╡σêùΦí¿.
                   ^
D:\PersonAction.java:1: illegal character: \187
∩╗┐package net.top.app.web.person;
 ^
D:\PersonAction.java:1: illegal character: \191
∩╗┐package net.top.app.web.person;
  ^
2 errors
13 warnings

C:\>
```

Comment: `unmappable character for encoding`  Looks like you're using an odd foreign character in your code that it can't handle.  Take those out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the help of javadoc there are  options for encoding/charset

I think you should set the `-encoding` which is the encoding name of your source.

> -encoding  name
>                Specifies the encoding name of the source files, such as EUCJIS/SJIS. If this option is not specified, the platform default
>   converter is used.
>
> -charset  name
>                Specifies the HTML character set for this document. The name should be a preferred MIME name as given in the IANA Registry @
>                http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets. For example:
>
> ```
>            % javadoc -charset "iso-8859-1" mypackage
>          would insert the following line in the head of every generated page:
>
>             <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
>
>          This META tag is described in the HTML standard @
>          http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#h-5.2.2. (4197265 and 4137321)
>
>       Also see -encoding and -docencoding.
>
>       -docencoding  name
>          Specifies the encoding of the generated HTML files. The name should be a preferred MIME name as given in the IANA Registry @
>          http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets. If you omit this option but use -encoding, then the encoding of the generated
> ```
>
> HTML files is determined by
>                -encoding. Example:
>
> ```
>            % javadoc -docencoding "ISO-8859-1" mypackage
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your source files have a different character encoding than the default encoding of your system (Windows-1252).

Use the [`-encoding` option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#encoding) on the command line when you invoke the `javadoc` tool and specify the correct encoding. (If you don't know what the encoding of your source files is, you'll have to find out. Maybe it's UTF-8).

For example:

```
javadoc -encoding "UTF-8" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your encoding is wrong (Maybe you use special characters in your comments or String constants). You should have a look at the [javadoc command](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#options). There are some character encoding parameters:

- `encoding` specifies the input encoding
- `docencoding` specifies the output encoding
- `charset` makes javadoc include a meta tag with encoding info